# how to scale down the size of DatePicker or TimePicker in API8 ? They are shown in one dialog

Tags: android, view, dialog, android-widget, datetimepicker

I want to use  DatePicker and TimePicker in one Dialog.In large screen phones,it works well，But in small one, it seems too large.And i'm using **API8**, i can't use the method setScaleX()/setScaleY().

How do i do that ? Or is there any other ways to show datepicker and timepicker in one dialog ? thanks.

this is the datetimepicker_layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datepicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timepicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TimePicker>

</LinearLayout>
```

in java file:

```
private void showDateTimeDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.datetimepicker_layout,
            null);
    TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
    tp.setIs24HourView(true);

    //hidden the minute picker
    View minuteView = ((View) ((LinearLayout) tp.getChildAt(0))
            .getChildAt(1));
    minuteView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Log.d(tag, "onClick " + "which  " + which);
        }
    };

    builder.setView(v).setTitle("order time").setPositiveButton("ok", listener)
            .setNegativeButton("cancel", listener).create().show();
}
```

ps：
[image: picture]

Comment: Maybe this is not a good question. :-(